# Help with Checkbox fields in Email Template

Tags: apex, email-template, administration, html

I have created an HTML version Email template, and trying to have one checkbox. So I have used input type ="checkbox", while previewing it is displaying perfectly but when I view in outlook its visible as a pair of square bracket.

Can someone help me on this.

**This is how it looks while I preview in Salesforce email template**
[image]

**This is how it looks in Outlook:**

[image]

**Code in HTML Version:**
[image]

Comment: Did you test in a separate client (e.g. gmail) to confirm the behavior?

Comment: it is HTML template, its working good in web mail but in outlook its failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to read [Using Forms in Email: Method or Madness?](https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-in-email/), and I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51638292/2132791) on Stack Overflow. Basically, your best choice is to conditionally hide the field in Outlook and link them to a page. You can't render forms in Outlook, which uses Microsoft Word in the background to render the email, which is ... limited compared to other modern clients.